# Get the word, from a sentence that the user is talking about

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

This is a little bit of a weird question.
I am creating a selfbot in Node.js. That responds naturally.
And I'm trying to extract a variable from a sentence. To see what the user is talking about. I find it really hard to explain, so here's an example.

Let's say the user types this to my bot (Random example):
**What does the word *baking* mean.**

This also has to work with:
**What is the meaning of *baking*?**

Is there any way the bot can find out that im talking about *baking*?
I'm trying to do this by hand. Without using any NPM packages.
Feel free to ask questions, because even I do not entirely know how to explain it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share what you have already tried with us!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not simple, and even less if you don't have a clear idea of your goals. Sounds to me like you want to determine the intent of a sentence, by hand? Something like https://dialogflow.com/ does?

Comment: @Luca I would if i had anything, Sorry.

Comment: @LuisSerrano yes, Im trying to do something like that. But I was wondering is there is a simpler way. That I could use for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit: ThuverX

```
let word
if(content.indexOf("what") !== -1 && 
content[content.indexOf("what")+1] !== "is")
    word = content[content.indexOf("what")+1]
else if(content.indexOf("meaning") !== -1)
    word = content[content.indexOf("meaning")+2]
else if(content.indexOf("means") !== -1)
    word = content[content.indexOf("means")-1]
```